# Behmann's proof of Infinitude of primes.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am having difficulty in understanding the proof of Behmann of Infinitude of primes. Can someone please explain the last part 'The proof is concluded by noticing....' which is in page $178$?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You have been asking *many* questions about different proofs that there are infinitely many primes.  Are you on a mission to understand every proof that there are infinitely many primes, or are you looking up all these proofs for a broader reason?

Comment: Being on a mission is fine with me. What I don't get is how math is fun when you a) have trouble understanding each and every proof of the infinitude of primes and b) show no inclination at all at doing the thinking yourself.

Comment: @franz ..how do you know I am having trouble understanding each and every proof..I ask only those which I don't understand..

Comment: Moreover, I understood the first part..I asked for the last paragraph..where did you see I asked for a whole proof?

Comment: Yeah .I was curious to look at some of he proofs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there are only $m$ primes.  The expression

$$\frac{p_i}{p_i-1} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_i}} = 1 + \frac{1}{p_i} + \frac{1}{p_i^2} +\cdots,$$

by geometric series.

So if the right hand side is multiplied out, you get every possible unit fraction.  So the right hand side must be equal to the harmonic series.  But we've just shown that  the harmonic series is strictly larger.  So there must be more than $m$  primes.

Comment: You didn't get my question..I meant last paragraph which is in page 178

Comment: The last paragraph starts on page 177.  Maybe you should be more clear about what your question really is.

Comment: See my edit....

Comment: See mine.......

Comment: Yeah.... I already got it... anyway..thanks..